# FIML for endogenous switching model with an endogenous explanatory variable

Tags: maximum-likelihood, stata

In an endogenous switching model, if there is an additional endogenous explanatory variable, we can either follow a control function approach (Murtazashvili and Wooldridge 2016), or a full information maximum likelihood approach. I tried both, but the full information maximum likelihood approach does not work out. **I suspect I've made some stupid mistakes in writing up the likelihood function or the Stata codes.** Hope someone can help me with this.

I provide the detailed setting of my model here:

\begin{align}
Y_{1i}^{*}=\mathbf{X}_{1i} \mathbf{\beta}_{11} + E_{i}\beta_{12} +\mu_{1i} \label{1} \\
Y_{2i}^{*}=\mathbf{X}_{2i} \mathbf{\beta}_{2} + \mu_{2i} \label{y2.23} \\
Y_{3i}^{*}=\mathbf{W}_{i} \alpha + \nu_{i}  \label{2} \\
E_{i}=\mathbf{X}_{1i} \mathbf{\gamma}_{1} + Z_{i}\gamma_{2} + \kappa_{i}  \label{3} \\
Y_{i}=\begin{cases}
         Y_{1i} \; \text{iff} \; Y_{3i}^{*}>0, \\
         Y_{2i} \; \text{iff} \; Y_{3i}^{*}\leq 0 \\
         \end{cases} \label{4} \\
Y_{1i}=\begin{cases}
         1 \; \text{iff} \; Y_{1i}^{*}>0, \\
         0 \; \text{iff} \; Y_{1i}^{*}\leq 0
         \end{cases} \label{5} \\
Y_{2i}=\begin{cases}
         1 \; \text{iff} \; Y_{2i}^{*}>0, \\
         0 \; \text{iff} \; Y_{2i}^{*}\leq 0
         \end{cases} \label{6} \\
Y_{3i}=\begin{cases}
         1 \; \text{iff} \; Y_{3i}^{*}>0, \\
         0 \; \text{iff} \; Y_{3i}^{*}\leq 0
         \end{cases} \label{7}           
\end{align}

let $\Sigma$ be the variance-covariance matrix of the error term $\mu_{1i}$, $\mu_{2i}$, $\nu_{i}$ and $\kappa_{i}$. We denote $\Sigma$'s diagonal terms (the variance) by $\sigma_{j}^{2}$, $j=1,2,\nu, \kappa$, and its off-diagonal terms (the covariances) by $\sigma_{jl}$, $j,l=1,2,\nu, \kappa$ and $j\neq l$. The properties of $\Sigma$ are following:

\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{A1}: \mu_{ji} \sim N(0, \sigma_{j}^{2}), j = 1, 2, \nu, \kappa;
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{A2}: \sigma_{12} = 0; \sigma_{2\kappa}=0;
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{A3}: \sigma_{1} = 1; \sigma_{2} = 1; \sigma_{\nu} = 1;
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{A4}: \sigma_{1\nu}\neq 0, \; \sigma_{2\nu}\neq 0; \sigma_{1\kappa} \neq 0.
\end{equation*}

Putting these assumptions together, $\Sigma$ can be written as:

\begin{equation}
\Sigma = 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & & & \\ 0 & 1 & & \\ \sigma_{1\nu} & \sigma_{2\nu} &1 & \\ \sigma_{1\kappa} & 0 & \sigma_{\kappa\nu}& \sigma_{\kappa}^{2}  \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

A1 are common assumptioins of maximum likelihood estimation. A2 is because $Y_{1i} (\text{or } E_{i})$ and $Y_{2i}$ are never observed together. A3 is because in Probit model, $\alpha$ can be identified only up to a constant (see the maximum likelihood function of Probit model, $\sigma_{1}$, $\sigma_{2}$, and $\sigma_{\nu}$ can not be identified). A4 means the switching model and $E_{i}$ are endogenous. We do not make any explicit assumption on $\sigma_{\kappa\nu}$.

The probability for the *i*th observation can be written as the following:

\begin{equation}
f(E_{i}, Y_{i}, Y_{3i})=\begin{cases} 
                      f(E_{i}, Y_{1i}=1, Y_{3i}=1) \; \text{if} \; Y_{3i}=1\&Y_{1i}=1 \\ 
                      f(E_{i}, Y_{1i}=0, Y_{3i}=1) \; \text{if} \; Y_{3i}=1\&Y_{1i}=0 \\
                      f(Y_{2i}=1, Y_{3i}=0) \; \text{if} \; Y_{3i}=0\&Y_{2i}=1 \\
                      f(Y_{2i}=0, Y_{3i}=0) \; \text{if} \; Y_{3i}=0\&Y_{2i}=0
                      \end{cases}
\label{sub_sec_bi_yes_lnfj}                      
\end{equation}
The first line of the equation above can be written as the following:

\begin{equation}
 f(E_{i}, Y_{1i}=1, Y_{3i}=1)= f_{\kappa}(\kappa_{i}) \int_{-\infty}^{X_{1i}\beta_1+E_{i}\beta_{12}} \int_{-\infty}^{W_i\alpha}f(\mu_{1i},\nu_{i}\vert\kappa_{i})d\nu_{i}d\mu_{1i}
\end{equation}

Notice that

\begin{equation}
\mu_{1i},\nu_{i}\vert \kappa_{i} \sim N_{2} \left(\begin{pmatrix}  \frac{\sigma_{1\kappa}\kappa_{i}}{\sigma_{\kappa}^{2}} \\   \frac{\sigma_{\nu\kappa}\kappa_{i}}{\sigma_{\kappa}^{2}}  \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
\sigma_{1}^{2}-\frac{\sigma_{1\kappa}^{2}}{\sigma_{\kappa}^{2}} & \sigma_{1\nu}-\frac{\sigma_{1\kappa} \sigma_{\nu\kappa}}{\sigma_{\kappa}^{2}} \\ \sigma_{1\nu}-\frac{\sigma_{1\kappa} \sigma_{\nu\kappa}}{\sigma_{\kappa}^{2}} &  \sigma_{\nu}^{2}-\frac{\sigma_{\nu\kappa}^{2}}{\sigma_{\kappa}^{2}}
\end{pmatrix} \right)
\end{equation}

We denote

\begin{equation}
\lambda_{1}=\frac{\sigma_{1\kappa}\kappa_{i}}{\sigma_{\kappa}^{2}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\lambda_{2}=\frac{\sigma_{\nu\kappa}\kappa_{i}}{\sigma_{\kappa}^{2}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\sigma_{1\vert \kappa}=\sqrt{\sigma_{1}^{2}-\frac{\sigma_{1\kappa}^{2}}{\sigma_{\kappa}^{2}}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\sigma_{\nu\vert \kappa}=\sqrt{\sigma_{\nu}^{2}-\frac{\sigma_{\nu\kappa}^{2}}{\sigma_{\kappa}^{2}}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\sigma_{\mu_{1}\nu \vert \kappa}=\sigma_{1\nu}-\frac{\sigma_{\mu1\kappa} \sigma_{\nu\kappa}}{\sigma_{\kappa}^{2}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\rho_{\mu_{1}\nu\vert\kappa}=\frac{\sigma_{\mu_{1}\nu\vert \kappa}}{\sigma_{1\vert \kappa}\sigma_{\nu\vert \kappa}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\mu_{1i}^{'} = \frac{\mu_{1i}-\lambda_{1}}{\sigma_{1\vert\kappa}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\nu_{i}^{'}=\frac{\nu_{i}-\lambda_{2}}{\sigma_{\nu\vert\kappa}}
\end{equation}

So,

\begin{equation}
 f(E_{i}, Y_{1i}=1, Y_{3i}=1)= \frac{\phi(\frac{\kappa_{i}}{\sigma_{\kappa}})}{\sigma_{\kappa}}{\Phi \left(\frac{X_{1i}\beta_{1}+E_{i}\beta_{12}-\lambda_{1}}{\sigma_{1\vert\kappa}}, \frac{W_{i}\alpha-\lambda_{2}}{\sigma_{\nu\vert\kappa}}, \rho_{\mu_{1}\nu\vert\kappa} \right)}
\end{equation}

Let's denote $\Phi(\mu_{1i}^{'},\nu_{i}^{'}, \rho_{\mu_{1}\nu\vert\kappa})$ as the standardized cummulative distribution function of $\mu_{1i},\nu_{i}\vert \kappa_{i}$, the log likelihood function can be written as the following:

\begin{align}
\ln L= \sum_{i=1}^{n}  \left\{ \left[\ln\phi(\frac{\kappa_{i}}{\sigma_{\kappa}})- \ln{\sigma_{\kappa}}+\ln{\Phi \left(\frac{X_{1i}\beta_{1}+E_{i}\beta_{12}-\lambda_{1}}{\sigma_{1\vert\kappa}}, \frac{W_{i}\alpha-\lambda_{2}}{\sigma_{\nu\vert\kappa}}, \rho_{\mu_{1}\nu\vert\kappa}  \right)}\vert_{Y_{1i}=1, Y_{3i}=1} \right] \right.\nonumber \\ \left.+\left[\ln\phi(\frac{\kappa_{i}}{\sigma_{\kappa}})- \ln{\sigma_{\kappa}} + \ln{\Phi \left(-\frac{X_{1i}\beta_{1}+E_{i}\beta_{12}-\lambda_{1}}{\sigma_{1\vert\kappa}}, \frac{W_{i}\alpha-\lambda_{2}}{\sigma_{\nu\vert\kappa}}, -\rho_{\mu_{1}\nu\vert\kappa}  \right)}\vert_{Y_{1i}=0, Y_{3i}=1} \right] \right.\nonumber \\ \left. +\left[\ln{\Phi \left(X_{2i}\beta_{2}, -W_{i}\alpha, -\rho_{2}  \right)}\vert_{Y_{2i}=1, Y_{3i}=0}\right] +\left[\ln{\Phi \left(-X_{2i}\beta_{2}, -W_{i}\alpha, \rho_{2}  \right)}\vert_{Y_{2i}=0, Y_{3i}=0}\right]  \right\}
\end{align}

The corresponding method-lf evaluator in Stata is:

```
    capture program drop myswitching_bi_endo_lf 
    program myswitching_bi_endo_lf

    args lnfj theta1 theta2 theta3 theta4 rho1 rho2 sig14 sig34 sig4

    tempvar sd1 sd3 mu1 mu3 eta1 eta3 kappa4 rho1dash 

    quietly generate double `sd1'=sqrt(1-`sig14'^2/`sig4'^2)
    quietly generate double `sd3'=sqrt(1-`sig34'^2/`sig4'^2)

    quietly generate double `kappa4'=$ML_y4-`theta4'

    quietly generate double `mu1'=`sig14'*`kappa4'/`sig4'^2
    quietly generate double `mu3'=`sig34'*`kappa4'/`sig4'^2

    quietly generate double `eta1'=(`theta1'-`mu1')/`sd1'
    quietly generate double `eta3'=(`theta3'-`mu3')/`sd3'

    quietly generate double `rho1dash'=(`rho1'-(`sig14'*`sig34'/`sig4'^2))/(`sd1'*`sd3')

    quietly replace `lnfj'=lnnormalden(`kappa4', `sig4')+ln(binormal(`eta1', `eta3', `rho1dash')) if $ML_y1==1&$ML_y3==1
    quietly replace `lnfj'=lnnormalden(`kappa4', `sig4')+ln(binormal(-`eta1', `eta3', -`rho1dash')) if $ML_y1==0&$ML_y3==1
    quietly replace `lnfj'=ln(binormal(`theta2', -`theta3', -`rho2')) if $ML_y2==1&$ML_y3==0
    quietly replace `lnfj'=ln(binormal(-`theta2', -`theta3', `rho2')) if $ML_y2==0&$ML_y3==0

    end
```

Comment: Yichen Tu has rightly pointed out that the upper limit of the integration did not include term $E_{i}\beta_{12}$. This mistake is now corrected. But, as Stata says, there are still some other mistakes. Much thanks to Yichen Tu.